# What is Laravel's similar method to PDO::FETCH_ASSOC?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, laravel-5.3

I am updating my php PDO website using Laravel Framework 5.3. I am finding Laravel very easy to use but there are few functions that I don't know the syntax to achieve results.

I have a Laravel controller

```
 public function index(){

        $posts = Post::latest()->get();

        return view('/home', compact('posts'));
    }
```

which I use in the blade to fetch data using a foreach loop

```
@foreach ($posts as $row)

@endforeach
```

which is similar to fetchAll() method in PDO

```
$row = $posts->fetchAll();
```

now I want the logic to get fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) like result, so that I can assign

```
$row = $posts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I have to do this because I want to use for loop in the blade to show the data, if I use foreach loop then it creates duplication for iterated result. Following is the PDO code that I have to update with Laravel

```
for($i=0; $i<$count_photos; $i++){

        $row_gallery = $get_photos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $pst_id = $row_gallery['post_id'];
        $img = $row_gallery['img_name'];


        echo '<div class="img_gallery"><div class="gallery'.$i.'"><a href="uploads/'. $img . '" data-lightbox="'.$pst_id.'"> <img class="img-responsive" src="uploads/'. $img . '"></a></div></div>';

      }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just get the first row from the table? If so, then just do `Post::latest()->first();` which returns just a single row/object.

Comment: How does a `Post` relate to your `$get_photos` query?

Comment: @Ross, I have two tables, one for the posts and one for the photos. The photos table can have multiple photos associated with a single post. I have used hasMany() relationship in the Model to fetch photos along with that post.

Comment: Cool. Are you just wanting to get one or all of the posts?

Comment: I am just trying to get one post along with its associated photos

Comment: I'd suggest reading https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations  specifically `Retrieving Polymorphic Relations`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The models will have already been fetched when you use `get()` so you'll be able to access the properties on the model straight away e.g.

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)

    {{ $post->title }} //assuming you have a "title" column in the database

@endforeach
```

You might find this helpful: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/7

---

### Edit

If you have the `photos` relationship set up in your `Post` model then you can [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relationship. Also, since you only want to load one post you can use `first()` instead of `get()` so you would end up with the following:

**Controller**:

```
public function index()
{
    $post = Post::with('photos')->latest()->first();

    return view('/home', compact('post'));
}
```

**Blade file**

```
@foreach($post->photos as $k => $photo)
    <div class="img_gallery">
        <div class="gallery{{ $k }}">
            <a href="{{ url('uploads/'.$photo->img_name) }}" data-lightbox="{{ $post->id }}">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ url('uploads/'.$photo->img_name) }}">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks @Ross for reply.  I can not use the foreach loop as I am trying to fetch data inside a for loop, if I use foreach then for every iteration it repeats the fetched data. I have to use fetch_assoc similar to have just one value for each iteration

Comment: @chris Are you just trying to get one post?